# LiDAR Analysis GUI (LAG). Make and Make install

Tags: 16.10

I have a programm from GIT: https://github.com/arsf/lag.

Author of this program has given instructions for its installation:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
cd lag/lidarquadtree
libtoolize && autoheader && aclocal && automake --add-missing && autoconf
./configure
make
sudo make install

cd ..
libtoolize && autoheader && aclocal && automake --add-missing && autoconf
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The first part (lidarquadtree) is installed without errors, But the second part is not (log make command):

```
MANY MANY MANY "undefined reference to"
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x36d4): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x36e3): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x36f2): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::compare(char const*) const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x36fd): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3712): undefined reference to `Gtk::ToggleButton::get_active() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3726): undefined reference to `Gtk::ToggleButton::get_active() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3788): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x37d8): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x37e4): undefined reference to `Gtk::ToggleButton::get_active() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x37f4): undefined reference to `Gtk::ToggleButton::get_active() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x380b): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x381a): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::compare(char const*) const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3825): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3840): undefined reference to `Gtk::ToggleButton::get_active() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x385a): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3886): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3892): undefined reference to `Gtk::ToggleButton::get_active() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x38f1): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x393f): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3958): undefined reference to `Gtk::ToggleButton::get_active() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3985): undefined reference to `Gtk::Widget::hide_all()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3a17): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3a6b): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3a89): undefined reference to `Gtk::ToggleButton::get_active() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3a9d): undefined reference to `Gtk::ToggleButton::get_active() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3aff): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3b4f): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3b5e): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3bae): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3c16): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3c66): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3c75): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3cc5): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3d56): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3da6): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3e06): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3e56): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3eb6): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3f06): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3f5a): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3faa): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x3fb9): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x404a): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x409a): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x40a9): undefined reference to `Gtk::Entry::get_text() const'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x410c): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x4150): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x4193): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x4222): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
src/ui/lag-AdvancedLoadDialog.o: In function `AdvancedLoadDialog::on_inside_rectangle_cb_toggled()':
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `Gtk::Widget::set_sensitive(bool)'
src/ui/lag-AdvancedLoadDialog.o: In function `AdvancedLoadDialog::on_inside_box_cb_toggled()':
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `Gtk::Widget::set_sensitive(bool)'
src/ui/lag-AdvancedLoadDialog.o: In function `AdvancedLoadDialog::on_inside_circle_cb_toggled()':
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `Gtk::Widget::set_sensitive(bool)'
src/ui/lag-AdvancedLoadDialog.o: In function `AdvancedLoadDialog::on_clip_x_cb_toggled()':
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x146): undefined reference to `Gtk::Widget::set_sensitive(bool)'
src/ui/lag-AdvancedLoadDialog.o: In function `AdvancedLoadDialog::on_clip_y_cb_toggled()':
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x194): undefined reference to `Gtk::Widget::set_sensitive(bool)'
src/ui/lag-AdvancedLoadDialog.o:AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text+0x1d6): more undefined references to `Gtk::Widget::set_sensitive(bool)' follow
src/ui/lag-AdvancedLoadDialog.o: In function `sigc::internal::typed_slot_rep<sigc::bound_mem_functor0<void, AdvancedLoadDialog> >::dup(void*)':
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text._ZN4sigc8internal14typed_slot_repINS_18bound_mem_functor0Iv18AdvancedLoadDialogEEE3dupEPv[_ZN4sigc8internal14typed_slot_repINS_18bound_mem_functor0Iv18AdvancedLoadDialogEEE3dupEPv]+0x1c): undefined reference to `sigc::trackable::trackable()'
src/ui/lag-AdvancedLoadDialog.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN18AdvancedLoadDialogC2ERKN4Glib6RefPtrIN3Gtk7BuilderEEE':
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x36): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3d): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x66): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x8f): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb8): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe1): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x10a): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
src/ui/lag-AdvancedLoadDialog.o:AdvancedLoadDialog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x133): more undefined references to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)' follow
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::run()':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::lock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `Glib::Cond::wait(Glib::Mutex&)'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::lock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `Glib::Dispatcher::operator()()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::DrawWorker(LagDisplay*)':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `Glib::Dispatcher::Dispatcher()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::Mutex()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `Glib::Cond::Cond()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x14d): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::Mutex()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x167): undefined reference to `Glib::Dispatcher::~Dispatcher()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `Glib::Cond::~Cond()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::lock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x194): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `Glib::Thread::join()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x1b2): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::~Mutex()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x1ba): undefined reference to `Glib::Dispatcher::~Dispatcher()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::stop()':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::lock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x200): undefined reference to `Glib::Cond::signal()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::~DrawWorker()':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x269): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::lock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x275): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x283): undefined reference to `Glib::Thread::join()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x297): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::~Mutex()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x29f): undefined reference to `Glib::Dispatcher::~Dispatcher()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x2a8): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::~Mutex()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x2b1): undefined reference to `Glib::Cond::~Cond()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x2bc): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::lock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x2d6): undefined reference to `Glib::Thread::join()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x2e6): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::~Mutex()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::draw(PointBucket**, int)':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x35b): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::lock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x370): undefined reference to `Glib::Cond::signal()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x38d): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::isDrawing()':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x3b1): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::lock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x3bd): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::run()':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::stop()':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x20e): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::~DrawWorker()':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x2f8): undefined reference to `Glib::Dispatcher::~Dispatcher()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::draw(PointBucket**, int)':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x382): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN10DrawWorkerC2EP10LagDisplay':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0x10): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0x17): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0x40): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0x69): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0x92): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0xbb): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe4): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o:DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0x10d): more undefined references to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)' follow
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::SelectionBox(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `Point::Point()'
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::SelectionBox(Point, Point, Point, Point)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x116): undefined reference to `Point::Point()'
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::move(double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x1d9): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::translate(double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x229): undefined reference to `Point::translate(double, double, double)'
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::SelectionBox(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::movePoint(int, double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x24c): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::translatePoint(int, double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x25c): undefined reference to `Point::translate(double, double, double)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:523: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «lag»
make[1]: *** [lag] Ошибка 1
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/meeeeeeeee/lag-master»
Makefile:373: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «all»
make: *** [all] Ошибка 2
```

**Why that command is not executed?**

Comment: Did you install all the required dependencies listed [here](https://github.com/arsf/lag) - in particular the `GTKmm` and `GTKGLextmm` development packages?

Comment: Yes, I did it. I can not understand is this: for example, that's error "src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::move(double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x1d9): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'".But here the "/ usr / local / include / lidar / quadtree" there file Point.h where the procedure is declared.

Comment: **Declarations** (from header files) are not the same as **definitions** - the latter come from actual libraries that are linked in the final stage of the build process - that's where your build is failing.

Comment: Okay. And how to fix it all?